# How to fetch data of the last 10 minutes from datestamp?

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I want to get the number of tweets that were tweeted in the last 10 minutes of the match. But to do that I need to select/get the last 10 minutes of my timestamp.

How can I do this in Impala/SQL?

This is what I currently have:
[image: What I have at the moment.]

Comment: WHERE official_end >= minutes_add(now(), -10)

Comment: Where exactly if I may ask?

Comment: The query works I think, but for some reason, it does not display anything? Do you know perhaps why? https://gyazo.com/dc7071e9691593f3b203ff962473b77a

Comment: Maybe your data? It all looks like 2017 and it is 2018. You could also just run: select  minutes_add(now(), -10) , and make sure it is what you are expecting.

Comment: Haha I think I didn't said it right. I don't need the now, I only need the last 10 minutes of the value inside the column official_end

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you need exactly. What is "the last 10 minutes" in that column. Edit your question and give an example.

Comment: So basically in a whole match, there are 10k+ tweets posted. I want to know how much tweets were posted in the last 10 minutes of the game. Official_end is a column that gives the date + time when the match has ended. Thus I need the last 10 minutes of that datestamp so I can fetch get the data in that time period.

Comment: Are the tweets stored in a different table? You already have the value of the last 10 minutes. You only need to select the tweets now with a value of > last10minutes

Comment: Yes they are stored in a different table. I'll try your advice. Thank you! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167673/discussion-between-kevin-and-mert-cakir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - If I understand from your comments now there is a separate tweets table, and you want to select the number of tweets 10 minutes before the game ended. I don't know the name of the tweets table, but something like this should work:

```
select COUNT(*) from tweets t
where t.tweet_date > 
(select DATE_SUB(g.official_end, interval 10 minute)
 from game g where g.game_id = t.game_id) and t.game_id = 10
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to puzzle it out. SQL is not my strongest skill. I'll let you know once I got it fixed! For now, I am currently puzzling it out with the columns from my other table and how to bind it together etc.

Comment: You are welcome Mert - no time like the present to learn SQL!